# protobuf-net: Cannot serialize type data, How can I define type data with protocol buffers?

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I am trying to create a simple in-memory grid that can be serialized using protocol buffers.

The idea is the user can create/define columns of any type (primitives or user defined as long as they're protocol buffers tagged).

My problem is you can't serialize Type data with protocol buffers so how can i achieve this?

Code is below showing how i'd hoped to code the Columns of the grid.

Thanks a lot.

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        Column colOrderId = new Column("OrderId", typeof(uint));
        Column colOrderDesc = new Column("OrderDesc", typeof(string));
        Column colPrice = new Column("Price", typeof(Price));
        Column colOrderDateTime = new Column("OrderDateTime", typeof(DateTime));

        var s = colOrderId.ToBArray();
    }
}

[ProtoContract, Serializable]
public sealed class Column
{
    public Column(string name, Type type)
    {
        Name = name;
        Type = type;
    }

    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public Type Type { get; private set; }
}

[ProtoContract, Serializable]
public sealed class Price
{
    public Price(double value, string currency)
    {
        Value = value;
        Currency = currency;
    }

    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public double Value { get; private set; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string Currency { get; private set; }
}

public static class ProtoBufEx
{
    public static byte[] ToBArray<T>(this T o)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(ms, o);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess that in protobuf v2 you are able to add a userdefined serializer for Type that serializes to the name of that type.

Comment: Another potential problem is that your types are immutable. I'm not sure if protobuf supports that out of the box, or if you need another custom serializer.

Comment: @CodeInChaos just for completeness, the private sets are fine. In v1 it would also need a parameterless constructor (again, private is fine); in v2 it can optionally skip the constructor, WCF-style.

Comment: The behavior I expect for such a type is that it will pass the values of the serialized fields into the constructor. No private reflection or bypassing of constructors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of issues in this approach; yes, in standard protocol buffers any kind of `Type` metadata is a bit naughty, as it isn't really interoperable, but I play a little loose with that in v2 **on an opt-in basis** - allowing you to send `object` etc as long as internally it still knows what you mean.

This, however, will get expensive for cell-by-cell work, even *with* the optimisations built in (it only sends the same type meta once, for example).

IMO, though, a far better option is to restrict yourself to a list of known types that are all known ahead of time. If you can do *that* there are some interesting tricks with inheritance that are pretty efficient and reasonably suited for this scenario. But essentially you'd have something like:

```
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(4, typeof(Column<int>))] // etc
abstract class Column {
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Name {get;private set;}

    public abstract object Value {get;private set;}
}
[ProtoContract]
class Column<T> : Column {
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public T TypedValue { get;private set;}
    override Value {...shim to TypedValue...}
}
// etc
```

(pseudo-code, incomplete)

I'd happily walk you through a lot of that, but you might also want to look at [this blog entry](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2010/10/datatable-life-in-old-beast.html) to see if using `DataTable` (much as I dislike it for data-access) might save some effort here.

Comment: Marc Gravell: My aim is for this to work cross-platform. So i guess using object is out? Also the grid is a simple light structure with just columns and rows not a huge .Net DataTable. It's basically i user-defined data store. thanks

Comment: @Dave there's simply no way of mapping that kind of data-structure to an easily interoperable protobuf (.proto) version, since the *core* protobuf spec is very minimal. The closest you could get would be lots of optional fields, but that would be horrible on most versions.l